# image blur when transform rotate and change width

Tags: css

Here's the example of what I tried to do:
https://jsfiddle.net/51cbw1g5/
HTML:

```
 <img src="http://test.grey-cat.biz/assets/images/logo-study.png">
```

CSS:

```
  img {
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  width: 143px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

img:hover {
  width: 100px;
    -moz-transform: rotate(16deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(16deg); 
    -webkit-transform: rotate(16deg); 
    -o-transform: rotate(16deg);
    transform: rotate(16deg);
}
```

On hover image gets blured, how can I fix that?

Comment: Is this browser-specific? Looks fine in Chrome 50.0.2661.94

Comment: maybe, I use firefox 46.0.1